# How to calculate values from two Queries in influxdb/grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm monitoring the cluster of 2 Linux Nodes with InfluxDB/Grafana. I collect metrics with telegraf http plugin. Metrics have the following format:

`host1 error=value1
host2 error=value2`

I have configured in Grafana that I could monitor `error` parameter for single nodes as following:

`Query A: SELECT "error" FROM "http" WHERE ("host" = 'node1')
Query B: SELECT "error" FROM "http" WHERE ("host" = 'node2')`

Can I monitor the summary `error` value over the cluster such as `error(node1) + error(node2)` ? How can I configure this in Grafana?

Comment: Flux project going to address these kinds of cross measurement computation.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean to get as a result seems like a join of two series. It is not possible to join two series in influxdb currently v1.7.

So what are your options to do something like it?

Create another series with the concatenation of strings and feed it to Influx. One way to do it is by using Kapacitor [join node](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/join_node/).

Comment: If values for error are numeric you can probably use MetaQueries Grafana plugin to make cross-series arithmetics. Not sure it can handle string values though.